# Rails tinyTDS running with MS SQL 2012

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2012, tiny-tds

I am testing rails applications with the new MS SQL 2012 server.
Installed it on a new Win 2008 R2 test system.
Installed Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.1 with all necessary stuff to connect MS SQL server.

When you configure the connection to a new SQL 2012 you can't connect, because the tinyTDS driver returns not supported platform.

The defintion is here:

```
.\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.0.16\lib\active_record\connection_adapters\sqlserver_adapter.rb:

Line 169:    SUPPORTED_VERSIONS          = [2005,2008,2010,2011].freeze
```

So first I wonder why there are 2010 and 2011 record inside.
Those sql versions don't exists as far as I know :).

So I change the line to:

```
Line 169:    SUPPORTED_VERSIONS          = [2005,2008,2012].freeze
```

Then I started a rails console, it worked.
I run some db migrations so far and everything looks well.

**So does anybody know ANY problems running this setup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest versions of the adapter.

Comment: Saw it meanwhile, too, but thanks for answer. I ran my modifications wihtout any problems and added also a client.execute("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647").do to get more then 1024 chars from varchar(max) content :)